# docker login failed at gitlab docker registry after gitlab update

Tags: docker, curl, https, gitlab, gitlab-ci

**Scenario**

- I updated gitlab (15.11.5 -> 16.1.2)
- After that my gitlab-ci pipeline failed

  - this builds a docker image and pushes it into the gitlab docker registry
  - connects to a remote staging server to call docker login and docker pull there

**The problem**
After the gitlab update, docker login on that remote server did not work anymore with

```
$ ssh deploy@$URL_STAGE docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_JOB_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY
Error response from daemon: Get "https://<my-domain>:5050/v2/": dial tcp 
<my-ip>:5050: connect: connection refused
```

`curl -i https://<my-domain>:5050` told me

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Fri, 14 Jul 2023 11:05:32 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: no-cache
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000
```

**curl fixed it**
I don't know if it was just a coincidence, but after calling this curl command on that remote server, the pipeline started to work again. So it feels like some known-hosts thing but the host is still the same?!
I think, the ssh certs are new as well! Is curl 'welcoming' new certs differently than docker login?

I searched for a solution for multiple hours and tried to run the pipeline multiple times. As ssh to the remote server and the gitlab gui and curl from my dev machine worked all the time, I don't think that there was some real temporary connection problem.

Any idea what curl potentially did to make docker login work again?

Answer (score 1):

The most likely explanation for why `curl` fixed the problem is that it forced the docker daemon to update its cache of the GitLab registry's TLS certificate.

When you run `docker login`, the docker daemon tries to connect to the registry using its cached copy of the TLS certificate. If the certificate has been updated, the connection will fail.
`curl`, on the other hand, does not cache TLS certificates, so it always retrieves the latest version from the registry.

---

However, the Docker daemon does not listen for changes in the operating system's certificate store. The Docker daemon utilizes certificates located in a Docker-specific directory (often [`$DOCKER_CERT_PATH`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/protect-access/#client-modes) or, by default, `~/.docker/{ca,cert,key}.pem`), not the certificates from the OS store.

The `curl` command, when run without specific options to write or modify certificates, will not update the system certificate store or any Docker-specific certificate. `curl` merely fetches and verifies the SSL/TLS certificate during its connection but does not store the certificate for future use or update any existing store.

Since the Docker daemon does not interact with the system-wide certificate store, and running a `curl` command would not affect the certificates Docker is using. As such, it is likely that some other factor caused the Docker login to succeed following the execution of the `curl` command.
I can only assume a system administrator or an automated process changed the certificates in Docker's specific directory.

Comment: This would explain it. To assess the probability: do you know that there is some mechanism the docker daemon could listen on? I mean, does the curl request update some OS certificate store?

Comment: @andymel After more research, the curl request does not update  some OS certificate store: see my edited answer.